# Magento 2 - How to customize Shipping Label pdf print-out

Tags: magento2, pdf, print, shipping-label

I want to change the design and layout of my print shipping label pdf print-outs to make a simple and clean print for the employes to work through.

Is there any extension / tutorial / anything else which shows how to make this possible ?